# Does non-relational OLAP Engine exist?

Tags: olap

Like a NoSQL Database, but for OLAP. Open Source of course :)

Edit:

OLAP engines use Relational DB behind the scenes. For example SAPBW can use Oracle, etc. What I meant was an OLAP engine WITHOUT this underlying Relation DB.  Sort of like a Google BigTable with OLAP functionality.

The OLAP DB can be gigantic since BigTable is about the same amount of Data, and I want to know if anybody has made a model for fusing both.

Answer (score 2):

[Palo](http://www.palo.net/) is an open source OLAP engine that does not use an RDBMS as a backend.  All data is stored in memory (and persisted to disk as CSV) so it's not suitable for very large amounts of data.

[datacube](https://github.com/urbanairship/datacube) is a new HBase-backed OLAP engine from Urban Airship.

Answer (score 1):

This is like asking if there are non-brick houses.  OLAP is non-relational, or rather, it's more of an application layer or optimized data structure that can live on a relational database.

You probably want to look at [Pentaho](http://pentaho.org/) - specifically [Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.org/).

Comment: OLAP engine uses Relational DB underground. SAPBW uses Oracle, etc. What I mean is OLAP engine WIHTOUT underlying Relation DB like a sort of Google BigTable with OLAP functionality.

OLAP DB can be gigantic since BigTable is about the same amount of Data, I want to know if anybody has made a model for fusionning both.

Answer (score 0):

There are several non-relational OLAP engines. Learn about OLAP engines like 'Druid' and 'Kylin'. There is also a big-data analysis platform like [Metatron Discovery](https://metatron-app.github.io/metatron-doc-discovery/en/discovery/part01/overview.html#bi) that uses it.